# Cannot resolve Symbol id

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView called "Notes", I'm trying to add an new recylerview called "Assignments" which will be created inside the notes recylerview item.
When I click on a recylerview item (notes) it send me to ClassworkActivity in which the assignments' recyclerview will be added to it.
So I want to add the assignment recyclerview as a child of the notes recyclerview.

Here's what I tried:

```
final AssignmentAdapter assignmentAdapter=new AssignmentAdapter(assignlist,this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(assignmentAdapter);

FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);


mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


String userID = mCurrentUser.getUid();


firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Notes").child(id).child("Assignments");
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            AssignListdata listdata=dataSnapshot1.getValue(AssignListdata.class);
            assignlist.add(listdata);

        }
        assignmentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

// fab
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddAssignmentActivity.class));
    }
});
```

But I'm getting the error on this line:

```
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().
child("Users").
child(userID).
child("Notes").
child(id).
child("Assignments");
```

since I didn't create the variable id : `child(id).` which is the id of the Notes List
Can anyone tell me how to declare this variable?

Another thing is that the assignments are created as a Notes in the NotesActivity, not in the ClassworkActivity!

[image: JSON tree]

Also, this is a github link of my project, Please take a look at it:
[Notes App](https://github.com/XLogger-g/RecyclerAdapter)

Answer (score 0):

When you click on recyclerView item of Notes, get the `noteID` usinng which position is clicked.

now when you open `ClassworkActivity`, bind that id with intent and get it in `ClassworkActivity` onCreate() and while creating `AssignmentAdapter` use that noteID as id.

pass noteId using intent as:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ClassworkActivity.class); // UPDATE CURRENT ACTIVITY NAME
myIntent.putExtra("noteID", noteID);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

and receive in `ClassworkActivity` onCreate() as:

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int id = mIntent.getIntExtra("noteID", 0);
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the assignments still created as a note and in the NotesActivity not in the ClassworkActivity

Comment: describe your question well, with all possible code

Comment: Yes it opens when I set itemView.setOnClickListener on the NotesAdapter. I added the JSON tree to understand more my issue and I'll add a github link on the project

Comment: in that listener you can obtain which position is clicked, and base on that position you can get note object from list bind in noteAdapter

Comment: I added a link of my project, can you please take a look ? Much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is there a turorial for this, because I couldn't find any example.